# azure databricks notebook - (Python) how to pass argument which is list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

Hi I want to pass [('file1', 'd', 1),('file2', 'w',2), ('file3', 'd', 5)] as argument to Azure databrics notebook and then I want to check if file1 was modified in last 1 day and file2 was modified in last 2 weeks and file3 was modified in last 5 days etc etc for all remaining tuples.
if all this is true then return True.
when I try use
dbutils.widgets.text('my_filelist','','')
my_filelist = dbutils.widget.get("my_filelist")
print(my_filelist)
this prints the string I passed but this is not list of tuples which I could then process, how to make this list of tuples? for example... list_of_tup = list(my_filelist) does not help
( overall goal is to develop generic all data files arrived check utility before doing ETL/ELT )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that similar to how it is done in this example -

```
returned_table = dbutils.notebook.run("LOCATION_OF_CALLEE_NOTEBOOK", 60) display(sqlContext.read.parquet(returned_table))
```

Comment: thanks Bharath. I could try this. for now I found that doing list_of_tup = list(eval(my_filelist)) serves my purpose as well.

Comment: colleague helped fixed it ...pass argument as list of tuples only i.e. [(filename, frequency, days/weeks/month] and then using eval and list process tuples